# Annotation disappeared from the library, which used instead?(saripaar)

Tags: android

I use `com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar` library in my project. [enter link description here](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)

I use `@Size` annotation. But nuw i sync my gradle and i have error. This annotation disappeared. I checked on githabe - it is not! 
But My colleague has updated gradle and he has this annotation. We have absolutely the same dependence in gradle. I did not change anything. I tried to clean up and rebuild the project.

```
maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

it really cleaned? I use instead? why it stayed another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshots on that library doesn't seem to be stable (I see only lower versions on their releases).
Also, on master, they [renamed](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/commit/4d0e9e5fbaf49a4ef4a1e9d7bffd1d5a16a6eef8) the `Size` annotation to `Length`

So you will be ok if you just change your Size annotation by Length too.

Comment: though I naschel this decision earlier than you said, still raise reputation. It is the right solution, thank you!